# Swap Serial pins of ESP8266?

Tags: serial, esp8266, espressif

I have designed and manufactured a PCB which contains an ESP8266 (ESP-WROOM-02D) chip with the serial uart pins connected to a 30pin connector. I made a mistake on the layout (first time designing a PCB), and have the RX (Pin 3) and TX (pin 1) pins connected incorrectly (swapped).

Is there a way to switch these pins in software? There's no nice way to physically modify and I was hoping to not have to have the boards manufactured again if I can avoid it.

Thanks!

Comment: no. there is not

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially still fix this by using `SoftwareSerial`.
Instead of using the hard-wired serial, you can create one in software and use any pins you'd like... Have a look at [this github project](https://github.com/plerup/espsoftwareserial).
This work-around however requires you to have two unused pins to assign to SoftwareSerial.

Comment: the linked SoftwareSerial library is bundled with esp8266 Arduino boards support package

Comment: Can I reassign the two hardware serial pins to software serial? It is hardwired to pins 1 and 3...

Comment: @tommy-b-10, how do you flash the sketch into the esp?

Comment: @Juraj I flash the initial sketch before the esp is soldered to the board, then future flashes are done OTA using the esp wifi.

Comment: Had another crack at this and realised I needed to set the pinmode to function_3 for pins 1 and 3 before calling softwareserial.begin. Works perfectly now! Is there any downsides to using softwareserial? I have it working at 115200 baud but a little concerned about stability. Cheers!